# SQL SELECT column letter prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I hate to have to post about this as I'm sure it's an easy one but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I'm pulling data from two tables and would like to prefix the ID with a letter to indicate which table it originated from. E.g.

```
SELECT 'A' + ID as originID FROM theTable
```

However I am getting the error

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int.
```

I presume this is because the '+' plus sign is causing SQL to try and add the two values together. I've tried a few different ways of doing it but get the same result, e.g:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(1) SET @a = 'A' "
SELECT @a & [ID] AS originID
```

In PHP I would normally use "." for concatenation and "+" for addition. Is there another method of concatenating strings in SQL? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `CAST`

```
SELECT 'A' + CAST(ID as VARCHAR(15))
FROM...
```

- [CAST and CONVERT (*Transact-SQL*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) <sup>credit to **Vaze**</sup>

Comment: More info on cast and convert here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: @JohnWoo :) You are fast and awesome on SQL +1

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try || for concatenation. this should work:

```
SELECT 'A' || ID as originID FROM theTable
```

Comment: I think it's because you are using T-SQL. I am not sure if this operator is valid in T-SQL. But I use it in PL/SQL.

Comment: Ah ok. Yes in this instance I am using T-SQL (SQL Server 2008).